# ggplot2 geom_pointline doesn't link centers of points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot with points and lines between them, but with spaces, in ggplot2, R. I have a shaded area in the plot, so some parts of points has gray and white background. I found `lemon` library with `geom_pointline` function.

```
ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max), fill = "gray", alpha = 0.35) +
geom_pointline(shape = 19, linecolor = "black", size = 4, color = "blue", distance = 2)
```

The result I get is shown below. As one can notice, the lines don't start and end in the middle of points, but rather at the top right and bottom left of the point. It gets even worse when I shorten the lines. I tried with many parameters but couldn't solve it. I would like the lines to start and end closer to the middle than it is now.
Thanks in advance!

[image: result]

Comment: you could pass lists of points to `geom_segment()`, but you'd need to work out your own spacing adjustment for each data point based on the angle of the line, which is not ideal.  Another approach would be to plot the line, then plot the points with large background-coloured markers, then replot the points with the colour you want to display, then finally overplot the ribbon with an alpha value set to allow the line and points to show through.  a bit clumsy but should be properly aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If switching to an other package is an option for you then one option to achieve your desired result would be `ggh4x::geom_pointpath` whichs similar to `geom_pointline` adds some padding around points along a line or path. One drawback is that TBMK it has no option to set different colors for the points and the lines. A hack would be to draw the lines via `ggh4x::geom_pointpath` then add a `geom_point` on top of it.

Using some fake example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

dt <- data.frame(
  x = seq(20, 160, 20),
  y = 1:8,
  min = 1:8 - runif(8),
  max = 1:8 + runif(8)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max), fill = "gray", alpha = 0.35) +
  geom_pointpath(shape = 19, size = 4, color = "black", mult = .25) +
  geom_point(shape = 19, size = 4, color = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: It worked exactly as I wanted, thank you!